# Docker maven build fails to download JARs

Tags: maven, jar, docker, boot2docker, dockerfile

I am using Docker to run a maven build but it stops downloading some JAR files after a while. It stops downloading jars after a while.

And it also stops at a different JAR on every run!

The build works on eclipse and my local machine but not on Docker.

I am using this image: https://hub.docker.com/_/maven/

Comment: can you add a reproducer, or more details so that one may reproduce what you do?

Comment: how looks your dockerfile ? try to attach to the container and use a tool like jstack to diagnose the problem : http://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-list-and-attach-to-docker-containers/

Comment: Thanks for the answers but problem is solved. I just had to run the image like 10 times for it to download all the jars.

Comment: doesn't sound like a *solution* to me :)

Comment: lol well I think it's just a connection problem on my end, and how to fix it is beyond my knowledge.